# Could not be found

Tags: c#-4.0, entity-framework-4, entityframework.extended

When I use the [`EntityFramework.Extended`](https://github.com/loresoft/EntityFramework.Extended) in my `RiceBuySellProvider` project, I got this error in my `main project`:

```
The type or namespace name I remove the 'RiceBuySellProvider' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
```

*From `MainProject` Image*
[image]

But when I remove the  `.FutureFirstOrDefault()` of `EntityFramework.Extended` from my `RiceBuySellProvider` and no errors found. Why?

**UPDATE**

When I use the `.FutureFirstOrDefault()` this will be the cause of the error.

```
public static ProductEntity GetProduct(string productNo)
{
    using (var con = new RiceBuySellEntities(ConnectionStr))
        return CompiledQueries.GetProCatTypeUnit.Invoke(con, productNo).FutureFirstOrDefault();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to add a reference to the assembly that holds the namespace you are importing.

Project Properties > Refernces

**Edit**
Its possible that the Rice assembly targets an incompatible framework, or that its bittyness (x86 / x64) is mismatched.

Comment: yes, of course we need to reference our `.dll`. but please try to figure out my question `:)`

Comment: No.  YOU figure out your question and ask what you mean.  It's not my job to play psychic.

Comment: okay. thats fine, obviously, the `RiceBuySellProvider` is already in my main project. thats why i wonder i got this error `:D`

Comment: +1 it might be. but this is strange. why this error occurred when I use the `.FutureFirstOrDefault()` of `EntityFramework.Extended`

Comment: The error indicates that the assembly has not loaded.  Any method on any class from the assembly will fail.

Comment: you have a point, but this is not might be the error because I downloaded the `EntityFramework.Extended` using the `Nuget` so I expect that the `.dll` have no errors.

Comment: You're probably right.  There is most likely an incompatibility between the dll and your project.